# Adding react native to laravel 8

Tags: laravel, react-native

I'm new to programming in both front-end and back-end as a fullstack developer.
I want to know if it is possible to use laravel 8 as backend and react native as a front-end and how to add react native to laravel project.

Comment: You wouldn't **add** React Native to a Laravel project. You would use something like Laravel for a backend `API` that your React Native app would consume. These are two separate topics both of which can be rabbit holes.

Comment: @Peppermintology : thank you for your comment , 1 year ago I started with MERN . With node and express , I could render some ejs and pure html files. so it's not the same here ?

Comment: The principles are the same. Node would be equivalent to Laravel, providing the backend `API` and React would be React Native. In MERN your React app would communicate with Node, in this example React Native will communicate with Laravel but it is unlikely they will be part of the same project.

Comment: @Peppermintology : thank you so much for the explanation and your time. much appreciated .